# C# Winforms App built on Windows 10 complains about dll on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-7

I have a winforms C# application, using dotnet framework 4.6.1. I recently got a new development machine, which runs windows 10, rather than windows 7.

Now when I try to run the application on a windows 7 machine, I get a strange error. The full text of the error is:

> The procedure entry point I_RpcBindingSetPrivateOption could not be located in the dynamic link library RPCRT4.dll.

I have also had a similar message about a different dll - api-ms-win-crt-private-I1-1-0.dll.

After I click on "OK" for this error, the application works fine.

I think this has to do with the fact that windows 10 and windows 7 have different versions of these dll's. But I'm not sure how I can prevent this error.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to prevent this error appearing?

Comment: Can you verify the integrity of the file in you win7 machine? run this in cmd as administrator

```sfc /VERIFYFILE=c:\windows\system32\rpcrt4.dll```

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework is installed on the Windows7 machine?

Comment: the sfc command did not find any integrity violations. I should note, both a user and myself have found this problem (me with a virtual machine running windows 7).

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2 is installed on my windows 7 test environment (virtual machine).